# Python Pandas Next Sequence Number

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,5,8, np.nan,np.nan], columns = ["UserID"])
```

I want to fill np.nan with next sequence numbers from starting with highest value + 1

expected result of df.UserID

```
[1, 5, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: There is only one groups with `NaN`s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) for counter and add original data with forward filling missing values:

```
df['UserID'] = df['UserID'].isna().cumsum().add(df['UserID'].ffill(), fill_value=0)
print (df)
   UserID
0     1.0
1     5.0
2     8.0
3     9.0
4    10.0
```